# Can we force the built-in Weather modern web part to dynamically show the Weather for the current user location.If not is there any other alternatives

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

We have a modern communication site inside SharePoint online tenant and we want to add a modern web part to a modern page to show the Weather of the login-in User location. Now we added the built-in Weather SharePoint modern web part, as follow:

[image]

But seems it only allow to specify a static location, or can we force it to dynamically show the weather of the login location?

If this is not possible with the built-in Weather web part, is there any 3rd part web parts we can use to achieve our need?

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as explained in [SE tour](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour) if my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using out of the box [weather web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-the-weather-on-your-page-4a86540e-0846-4fc0-bad0-1a82fcd430fc) in SharePoint online.

This web part only shows the weather of location(s) you choose in web part configuration.

---

If you want to show the weather of currently logged in user, you have to develop custom SPFx web part on your own.

Here's one sample which will help you to get started with: [Weather Information](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-weather-information)